CodeceptJS with Playwright Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': Write permission denied
codecept.config.js
/** @type {CodeceptJS.MainConfig} */
exports.config = {
  tests: './codecept/*.spec.js',
  output: './codecept/screenshots',
  helpers: {
    Playwright: {
      url: 'http://localhost',
      show: false,
      browser: 'chromium',
      waitForTimeout: 30000,
      permissions:['clipboard-write','clipboard-read']
    },
    MockRequest: {
      require: './codecept/Playwright_helper.js',
    },
  }
}

test.spec.js
const editorSelector = '.monaco-editor'
  await I.waitForElement(editorSelector, 10)
  await I.seeElement(editorSelector)
  await I.click(editorSelector)
  I.wait(1)
  const selectAllKey =
    process.platform === 'darwin' ? 'Command+A' : 'Control+A'
  await I.pressKey(selectAllKey)
  await I.pressKey('Delete')


  I.executeScript(async (text) => {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
  }, jsYaml.dump(irData.invalidVersion)); 

I have the above codecept.config.js and already set clipboard-read & clipboard-write permissions, i need to paste some text to my react-monaco-editor to verify the content.
But i am getting the following error in headless mode (my jenkins will always running in headless mode, and browser mode does not make any sense)
page.evaluate: NotAllowedError: Failed to execute 'writeText' on 'Clipboard': Write permission denied.

